# I want to conditionally copy a range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to conditionally copy a range from a table that have 10 rows and 3 columns

I'm using this:

```
Sub COPIAR()

Worksheets("01").Range("T3:AA13").Copy
 
End Sub
```

I want to copy the rows, and if the first column have no value, the VBA will skip the entire row

I tried this, but now im getting erron on this section "Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfcell.Resize(dr, cCount)"

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyCriteriaRows()
    
    Const sName As String = "GERAL"
    Const srgAddress As String = "B3:I13"
    Const dName As String = "GERAL"
    Const dfCellAddress As String = "B4"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(srgAddress)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If Len(CStr(Data(sr, 1))) > 0 Then
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfcell As Range: Set dfcell = dws.Range(dfCellAddress)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfcell.Resize(dr, cCount)
    drg.Value = Data
    
End Sub
```

Heres prints from my worksheet(starting from the on the first row bellow CC - B3:I13, note that i have hidden columns

[image]

I forgot a detail, my table has formulas, maybe this is preventing me from copying to the clipboard

Comment: If there is no data >0 then there will be no result. I added the following line to cover this: `If dr = 0 Then Exit Sub`. You could decorate it with a `MsgBox`.

Comment: It still doesn't copy anything, I believe it might be something about the dName, "Const dName As String = "Sheet2" ( what is dName ?? )

Comment: It's the (tab) name of the destination worksheet, the worksheet that you are copying to.

Comment: Got it, I didn't put the purpose for sure, I intend to copy only to the clibpoard (like a CTRL C )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Criteria Rows

- Adjust the destination values: the worksheet name and the first cell address.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyCriteriaRows()
    
    Const sName As String = "01"
    Const srgAddress As String = "T3:AA13"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dfCellAddress As String = "A2"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(srgAddress)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If Len(CStr(Data(sr, 1))) > 0 Then
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr

    If dr = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfcell As Range: Set dfcell = dws.Range(dfCellAddress)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfcell.Resize(dr, cCount)
    drg.Value = Data
    
End Sub
```